# hold event on image

Tags: c#, xaml, events, windows-phone-8

If i have an image with an Hold event and what to do something when you are finished holding on the image. First you Hold and it sets visibility on some things then when you stop holding on the image it should show what it was hidning in the first place.

Now i have only done this so far:

```
<Image x:Name="showMe" Source="/Assets/ViewPass.png" Width="48" Height="48" Margin="360,11,22,11" Hold="passShow_Hold_1"/>
```

and then just some code to show and hide some boxes:

```
private void passShow_Hold_1(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e)
{
  losenord.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
  visalosenord.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
}
```

Can i make a completed event for the hold gesture to make this work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store some state inside onHold method.
And attach one more event handler on  `MouseLeftButtonUp`.

After you need to check, if onHold event handler was executed then you can revert changes.